# Codeigniter upload working offline but not online

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I wanted to upload a 100 x 100 pixel image as a logo on my website for each user. It works on my localhost but doesn't work online (image is not uploaded). Well the concept is simple I just upload it and rename the image base on their ID's then display it on their page for them to view it. Another thing, the localhost version changes the image on the specified path but doesn't display it after upload somethimes but sometimes it works just fine. Well that not a big case here I just think that it might be a clue for solving this problem. Here's my code so far:

this is declared on top:

```
$data['base'] = $this->config->base_url();
$data['check_error'] = false;
$data['error_message'] = array();
$data['id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
```

This is the code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])){
                    $new_name = $data['id'];

                $config['upload_path'] = './Logos/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif';
                $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
                $config['max_size'] = '100';
                $config['max_width']  = '100';
                $config['max_height']  = '100';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
                    {
                        array_push($data['error_message'], "You have the following errors in your entry:\n");
                        array_push($data['error_message'], "- Logo must be 100x100 pixels in size not exceeding 100KB with JPG,PNG or GIF format");
                        array_push($data['error_message'], "\nLogo upload failed.");
                        $data['check_error'] = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                        //DO UPDATE PART HERE
                        $file = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
                        rename($config['upload_path'] . $file, $config['upload_path'] .$new_name.'.jpg');
                        //GO TO SETTINGS
                        $this->load->helper('url');  
                        redirect($data['base'].'settings');

                    }
                }
```

HTML:

```
 <tr>
    <td><p class="titles">Logo</p></td>
    <td>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="fileName" class="file_input_textbox" readonly="readonly">

        <div class="file_input_div">
          <input type="button" value="Browse" class="file_input_button" />
          <input type="file" class="file_input_hidden" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName').value = this.value" id="upload" name="userfile" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<p class="titles">100px x 100px jpg, png or gif only.</p>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><p class="titles">Current Logo</p></td>
<td>
    <img src="<?php if(is_array(@getimagesize($base."Logos/".$id.".jpg"))){echo $base."Logos/".$id.".jpg";}else{echo $base."Logos/default.jpg";} ?>"  style="margin:0px 0px 0px 90px;"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

I also use CodeIgniter_2.1.3 and 5.4.3 in PHP locally and 5.2.17 online. Going nuts haha!

Comment: have you checked the "Logos" folder permission online?

Comment: yes. it's already set to permission 777.

Comment: so even if i upload gif/png after renaming, the file is turned into jpg?

Comment: you are setting error messages but not retreiving it.

Comment: forcefully yes. I also think it's a bad idea anyway it's still working so I don't really mind that part. :)

Comment: `does not work` means file gets not uploaded or something else?

Comment: @itachi it is retrieved on body onload where it's passed into javascript then return an alert dialog. Well my main concern is the upload I just wonder why it reacts that way online. I think I need to cross that out. Editing the question. :)

image not uploaded. BTW.

Comment: what error message you are getting?

Comment: The one I set: "You have the following errors in your entry:
- Logo must be 100x100 pixels in size not exceeding 100KB with JPG,PNG or GIF format
Logo upload failed." when I upload greater than 100x100px img or file of other format. Online and offline it works it just it reacts differently online. Given that I assume it runs down on my if statement.

Comment: that's the error message you are setting, not the original which CI gives. you can retreive it by `$this->upload->display_errors()`. that's the actual error why it fails.

Comment: uhh, I think we had a misunderstanding. the error only appears when I upload a file of invalid format or dimensions. As I said it works offline where I mean the photo is uploaded without any errors but with minor glitches which I don't really mind. but online it doesn't upload the image at all. Which is why the error won't show up unless I choose a file of invalid format.

Comment: Could be the rename() function, your passing  it './Logos/' when it may want an absolute path (www/var/something/nanananana/htdocs/logos/), depending on your server setup. I had a similar problem when moving from the test environment to the liver server.

Comment: You should look into the file name part. Firstly you have set the condition encrypt_name to true. While you anyway rename your file to the id this is not neccesary. Also you set the new filename to be "user_id.jpg" - this will never work on a GIF or PNG image... Furthermore when moving from local to web server always dig into the upload path, delimiters and permissions. It just might be the upload path messing it up for you.

Comment: so I get two votes for upload path. thanks to both of you. Will try to use an absolute path now. :)

Comment: @KaHeL, worth noting that you should be able to use relative paths such as './Logos/' with any of codeigniter's functions, and it will work just fine ( in theory ). However, any native php functions (such as rename()) will expect an absolute path.

Comment: Also, unless there is a reason for using php's rename() , you could just use codeigniter's upload class to do it for you. $config['file_name'] = 'new file name.jpeg'.

Comment: Hi @jtheman thanks! Your advice works perfectly. Although I don't use the relative path anymore since it's just giving me an error of invalid path or whatsoever. I just applied what itachi says and found out that the problem is the file itself. although it is in PNG, GIF or JPG format it still returns a invalid format error. Also thanks for the that comment itachi. jtheman please feel free to add your comment as the answer so I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks for helping everyone. Well actually I solved it by limiting the user to only upload JPG images. hehehe!

Comment: @Jeemusu I need to rename the file since I will use it on the other code I created. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the file name part. Firstly you have set the condition `encrypt_name` to true. While you anyway rename your file to the id this is not neccesary. 
You set the new filename to be equal to

```
$data['id'].".jpg"
```

this will never work if uploaded file is a GIF or PNG image...